# Need help with study plan

Tags: study, planning

I am 1700-ish player and have too much time to play, and I didn't choose a study plan. I searched on the web about it, but no one has clearly defined study plan except chess.com and their study plan is trash. I wanted for a help from someone better or same rating like me.

Comment: There are many questions on this site asking basically the same question about how to improve. If you search using the Search function in the top left corner you will likely useful answers. As you say, study plans are trash. Nobody else can tell you what is a good amount of time per day to spend on tactics, endgames, openings, analyzing your own games, etc. Only you or your coach can do that.

Comment: Thx, I will look then

Comment: Related: [on basic practice routines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/23587/3594), links therein and the [10's of already answered questions on this topic](https://chess.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+improve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to develop a study plan you'd basically have to figure out your strengths/weaknesses and formulate a goal that you want to achieve.

In practice this means that a stronger player would have to analyze your games, but also (particularly at higher level) look at other things such as psychological factors, fitness, etc.

Ideally that coach would spend lots of chess time with you, so being somebody from your area would be preferable to having a random guy from the internet.

Unless you have money to burn or are super serious, IMO the most reasonable would be (if possible) to find a friendly chess club in your area with strong enough players. In my experience players in a club are usually very willing to give advise or tips to improve.

If you are objective enough, you could also try to figure out what you should train for yourself, however at a rating of 1700 that would be difficult to do. In any case you should always analyze your own games to improve and learn what to focus on next.

Once you know what to train for, there is plenty of information on this and other websites concerning improving in a particular area of chess.

Comment: Ok! You are helpful!