# What's a good way to learn openings when coming back to chess as a former 1400-1600 player?

Tags: opening, beginner

my question can be seen in the title. I used to play chess competitively in my teenager-years and would like to come back to it now. The important stuff is still in my head and I am not doing too bad when playing rapid online, but my opening-knowledge has been erased nearly entirely. I am going to play a local tournament soon and would like to learn some openings at least on the surface, so what's a good way to do so?

Comment: What did you play in these teenager years?

Comment: I mainly played French opening, Sicilian and Wolga gambit against d4, and 1.e4 2.Lc4 with white

Comment: @Daniel There's a lot of content out there. You can browse an opening tree based on lines you still remember and brush up on some basic move order, e.g. [lichess opening explorer](https://lichess.org/analysis#explorer). There are also a ton of video series out there, both on youtube and other places like the [chess24 series](https://chess24.com/en/learn/videoseries?lang=en). On the other hand, try to focus more on remember/learning how to reason about openings, as opposed to memorizing entire move orders, see for instance the discussions [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/20022/3594).

Comment: The best way to learning at your skill level is not learning it at all